# hasMany in Cake PHP not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table called group_joins:
The fields for above table is like,

```
1)id,
2)group_id,
3)user_id,
4)created
```

And another two table are users, and user_groups,
group_id reference to primary key of user_groups table, and user_id reference to primary key of users table.

Now I have create a model called GroupJoin and I want to association the above two table (users, user_groups) table with group_joins, that I can fetch all the users who have joined to this group.

I am passing group_id to the action as a parameter. And I have to fetch all the users belongs to that group.

My model is as follows:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'UserGroup' => array(
        'className' => 'UserGroup',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        )
    );

var $hasMany = array(   
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',     
        )
    );
```

And in my controller the query is as follows:

```
$groupArrs = $this->GroupJoin->find('all',array('conditions'=>'GroupJoin.group_id ="'. $group_id.'"'));
```

but it shows SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'User.user_id' in 'field list'

then how do I get all the users who are belongs to that group.

Answer (score 0):

First your naming of the the join table does not follow the CakePHP conventions. It should be groups_users (Model name for that: GroupsUser) not groups_join or whatever the table name is. See also [this pag](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)e.

Your associations should be:

- User hasAndBelongsToMany UsersGroup
- UsersGroup belongsTo User
- UsersGroup belongsTo UserGroup

When an user ONLY can belong to one user group you do not need the join table at all. If you now try the same query (UsersGroup.group_id => $groupId) it should work.

Also you're not follwing the conventions for variable names in CakePHP: It should be $groupId and not $group_id. And use the proper visibility scope keywords instead of "var".

Answer (score 0):

Create user_id as a  foreign key with user table in your database .

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to follow the example of burzum.

Your Models would looks like this :

```
class User extends AppModel{
        public $hasMany = array(
      'UserGroup' => array(
          'className' => 'UserGroup',
           'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );        
}

class Group extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'UserGroup' => array(
           'className' => 'UserGroup',
           'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
    )
    );

}
class UserGroup extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
       ),
       'Group' => array(
         'className' => 'Group',
         'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Hope this would help.